# UnAuthorised AzureServiceTokenProvider CosmosDb

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-cosmosdb

I have this code, which returns the access tokens for cosmos db

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

// Authenticate to the Azure Resource Manager to get the Service Managed token.
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/");

// Setup the List Keys API to get the Azure Cosmos DB keys.
string endpoint = $"https://management.azure.com/{resourcePath}";

// Add the access token to request headers.
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

// Post to the endpoint to get the keys result.
var result = await _client.PostAsync(endpoint, new StringContent(""));

// Get the result back as a DatabaseAccountListKeysResult.
DatabaseAccountListKeysResult keys = await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<DatabaseAccountListKeysResult>();
```

This worked until recently and I can't figure out what i need to authorize to get it to work.

The code gets the accessToken without issue, and the header is complete, but i result always comes back unauthorized.

Any suggestions would be appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had added an AzureDefaultCredentialsAuthorizationMessageHandler in my dependency injection extensions method which was causing the Authorization header to be over written.

All sorted DUH!!